# Problems with babel and \MakeUppercase in different versions of MikteX

Tags: babel

There is a problem that the same code in different versions of MikTeX works in different way.

Suppose we have the folowing LaTeX code

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{$\noexpand\sin(x)$}

\end{document}

(here one can use any language option with babel package, it doesn't matter).

In old versions of MikTeX (including MikTeX produced by Basic installer basic-miktex-22.10-x64.exe, version 10/17/2022, without updates), this code generates "sin(x)".

In other words, \noexpand is ignored here.

If I install basic-miktex-22.10-x64.exe, version 10/17/2022 and install all possible updates, \noexpand is not ignored here, so this code generates simply "(x)".

The problem is that my specific style file where \MakeUppercase is used should work in the same way with all MikTeX installations, both new and "not so new" (not the very last version with all last updates).

Is it possible to modify this code so that it works in both old and new MikTeX installations?

Thank you,

Yours,

Andrei Malokostov

Comment: well the easiest would be probably to use `\usepackage[overload]{textcase}`, then you can simply remove the `\noexpand`. But with the new `\MakeUppercase` \noexpand should probably not eat a following command, so you could open an issue at the latex2e github.

Comment: It fails also without `babel`. The way LaTeX deals with case changing has been rewritten. Without `\noexpand` works for me.

Comment: Javier Bezos, you are right, it fails also without babel.  But I cannot simply remove \noexpand because it will not work on "slightly old" MikTeX installation.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer, thank you for your idea, I have opened issue 1034, https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1034